# Unable to match a variable using grep because of back slash

Tags: bash, variables, grep, pattern-matching

[image][image]I have variable whose value is set as AMB529\SPB_REPORTING and when i am trying to find a match with its value it is not working because of back slash. Have tried both double and single quote but no luck.

Below is example

var=AMB529\SPB_REPORTING
cat text.txt | grep "$var"

It is taking value of $var as AMB529SPB_REPORTING and thus pattern match is not working.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Use `grep -F` to disable interpretation of the search string.

Comment: thanks for response. I had tried it but it did not help

Comment: Then your variable contained the wrong string in the first place. Use `var='AMB529\SPB_REPORTING'` together with `grep -F`.

Comment: I tested it here with defined with single quotes and a file called 'f' containing the same string, which works great as Socowi says.  Also no need to cat with grep.

 `var='AMB529\SPB_REPORTING'`
and 
 `grep -F "$var" f`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` command can be used to display lines from the files: `cat` is useless here.

there is a missing `;`, in order to define the `var` variable in the current shell (not in the execution environment of the `cat` command)

a regular expression containing a `\` followed by any ordinary character will be used as if the `\` character is not present (see `man 7 regex`).

@Socowi was right, the value assigned to `var` seems to be a filename (ordinary string) not a REGEX.

Moreover 2 `'` (quote) should be used when assigning a value to `var` in order to inhibit `pathname expansion`

Give a try to this:

```
var='AMB529\SPB_REPORTING' ; grep -F "${var}" text.txt
```

---

With bash builtin command `read` there is the same behavior (see `read --help`): the `\` is removed when it is followed by an ordinary character.

```
-r   do not allow backslashes to escape any characters
```

Give a try to this:

```
while IFS= read -r line ; do
   grep -F "${line}" text.txt
   # etc.
done
```

Comment: Have tried it also but no luck. Pasted the screenshot in original question.

Comment: You could try to debug with ```set -x ; var=AMB529\SPB_REPORTING ; grep -F "${var}" text.txt ; set +x```

Comment: also double check that the ```AMB529\SPB_REPORTING``` string exists in the text.txt file.

Comment: Ok let me try it. I have pasted the screenshot showing output with set -x . Seems value of variable is not set correctly.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: the bash is first performing a ```pathname expansion``` before assigning the value to ```var```: the ```\``` is removed. The answer had been modified.

Comment: thanks it works for me outside the bash script. But i am using while loop in script and there still it is not working. So how can i fix it in while loop. Below is example.

while read line
do 

#having same issue while assigning the value AMB529\SPB_REPORTING to variable line.

Comment: @HiteshKataria : the answer had been updated. Use ```while IFS= read -r line ; do``` etc.